# How can I create a default exception handler that uses JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

In my JavaFX application, I would like to create a global uncaught exception handler which creates a dialog window that displays an error message and the stack trace of the exception, and then terminates. I'm using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` and creating the dialog in there, but the code in the exception handler itself keeps throwing an exception whenever it's called.

The reason is that when any uncaught exception is thrown in the JavaFX Application Thread, the JVM terminates the thread. And the JavaFX thread *must* be running to create JavaFX components - therefore a dialog like that can't be created in the exception handler... So my question is what is the best way to do this? I would like to display a message to the user whenever an uncaught exception occurs, rather than having the application just terminate suddenly.

This is what I have been using:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((Thread t, Throwable e) -> {
        Dialogs.create().title("Error")
            .message("An uncaught exception was thrown in thread \"" + t
                    + "\". Click below to view the stacktrace, or close this "
                    + "dialog to terminate the application.")
            .style(DialogStyle.NATIVE)
            .showExceptionInNewWindow(e);
        Platform.exit();
    });

    primaryStage.show();
    method();
}

public void method() throws IOException {
    //Performs file i/o operations and throws IOException if an error occurs
    throw new IOException();
}
```

More exceptions may also be thrown later in the program. (I am using the ControlsFX library to create the dialog window, by the way.) This is the error message I'm getting when I run the code:

```
Exception in Application start method

Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

Comment: Which version of JavaFX are you running? I believe this was [addressed in version 8](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-15332).

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I created a simple test and it worked fine (in Java 8, failed spectacularly in JavaFX 2.2).

Comment: I added my exception handling code. All exceptions are thrown after this point

Comment: Still works fine for me, with the exact code you posted. You need to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, can you post the exceptions that are thrown in the exception handling code? Are the original exceptions being thrown on the FX Application Thread or on a background thread?

Comment: The exceptions are thrown on the FX Application Thread, but I plan to create background threads later that will also throw exceptions. Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() will handle those the same way, right?

Answer (score 3):

I **think** that what is happening here is that exceptions thrown in the `start()` method are caught by the code that invokes that method. So anything thrown in the `start()` method is not handled by your exception handler (it's not an *uncaught* exception).

However, exceptions thrown after the `start()` method has completed are handled by your exception handler.

Note, however, that the exceptions will be handled in the thread in which they are thrown. So your code will work as long as those exceptions are thrown on the FX Application Thread, but will not work for exceptions that are thrown in a background thread (because you can't create and show a dialog in a background thread).

To cover all eventualities:

1. If it's possible for an exception or error to be thrown in the `start()` method, place that code in a `try` - `catch` block and handle in the usual way.
2. Set the *default* uncaught exception handler to invoke the code to show the dialog using `Platform.runLater()`. This will handle exceptions thrown outside the FX Application Thread.
3. Set an uncaught exception handler on the FX Application Thread to invoke the code to show the dialog directly.

Example (errors are thrown in the `start()` method with 50% probability):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialogs;
import org.controlsfx.dialog.DialogStyle;

public class UncaughtExceptionHandlerExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)  {

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, e) -> Platform.runLater(() -> showErrorDialog(t, e)));
        Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(this::showErrorDialog);

        try {
            Button button = new Button("Create error");
            button.setOnAction(event ->  {
                throw new Error("Boom!");
            });

            Button backgroundErrorButton = new Button("Create error in background thread");
            backgroundErrorButton.setOnAction(event -> {
                new Thread(() -> {
                    throw new Error("Boom");
                }).start();
            });
            HBox root = new HBox(5, button, backgroundErrorButton);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 80);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

            if (new Random().nextDouble() < 0.5) {
                throw new Error("Boom");
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            showErrorDialog(Thread.currentThread(), t);
        }
    }

    private void showErrorDialog(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        Dialogs.create().title("Error")
        .message("An uncaught exception was thrown in thread " + t
                + ". Click below to view the stacktrace, or close this "
                + "dialog to terminate the application.")
        .style(DialogStyle.NATIVE)
        .showExceptionInNewWindow(e);
      Platform.exit();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Incidentally, I don't think it's true that the JVM terminates the FX Application Thread if an uncaught exception occurs on it.

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes sense now that the exceptions were being caught by the code that calls start(); I will add your suggestions to my code. One question though, why is number 3 necessary in your list of eventualities? If the JavaFX thread doesn't have its own handler then won't exceptions thrown on the JavaFX thread still be handled by the default handler?

Comment: What I have done is to keep the call to Platform.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() the same as in my original post, and put the rest of the start() method in a try block with catch block calling Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(Thread.currentThread(), e); It seems to work fine

Comment: That won't work if you get an uncaught exception in a background Thread, though, will it?

Comment: It's in a call to Platform.runLater(); Sorry, I should have specified

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the `platform.runLater()` method to create the dialog component in the JavaFx main thread when the exception occurs.